# webpacker: including javascript from a gem (js-routes)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker, js-routes

I'm trying to use the [JS routes gem](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes) with [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) from Rails 5.1 but can't figure out how to include the `js-routes.js.erb` in webpack's `app/javascript/packs/application.js`.

`import 'js-routes'`

leads to

`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "js-routes"`

Which likely means that webpack is unable to locate the javascript in the included gem. This is probably connected to this [webpacker's github issue](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/21).

What is the best workaround for this issue right now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the technique described in the [very advanced setup](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes#very-advanced-setup) part of the JsRoutes documentation:

```js
// app/javascript/routes.js.erb

<%= JsRoutes.generate %>
export default this.Routes
```

And then in your application pack:

```js
// app/javascript/packs/application.js

import Routes from '../routes.js.erb'
// Note the .erb extension!

// If you want it to be available globally for some reason:
window.Routes = Routes
```

Comment: One notice, if you get error like: "Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)". You probably don't have erb loader. To install it you should read short description on webpacker docs: https://github.com/rails/webpacker#erb

Answer (score 0):

If you want more js only dev process, you can

1. pre-generated `app/assets/javascripts/routes.js` with built-in task
   `rake js:routes`
2. add to

   ```
   # config/webpacker.yml 
   ...
   resolved_paths: ['app/assets/javascripts']
   ...
   ```
3. reference them as `import routes from './routes.js'`
4. regenerate it after any routing changes with `rake js:routes`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`webpacker`](https://github.com/rails/webpacker), you might want to check out [`js_from_routes`](https://github.com/ElMassimo/js_from_routes), which doesn't require advanced setup, as it's designed for an `import`-based setup.

For each endpoint that you'd like to access from JS, it will [generate a method](https://github.com/ElMassimo/js_from_routes/blob/master/spec/support/sample_app/app/javascript/requests/VideoClipsRequests.js#L32-L33) that can help you [build a URL](https://github.com/ElMassimo/js_from_routes/blob/master/spec/support/sample_app/app/javascript/requests/VideoClipsRequests.js#L8-L9) or make a request.

```rb
resources :video_clips, export: true
```

By using it [in combination](https://github.com/ElMassimo/js_from_routes/blob/master/spec/support/sample_app/app/javascript/services/ApiService.js#L32) with [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios), these generated helpers can be convenient and easy to use:

```js
import VideoClipsRequests from '@requests/VideoClipsRequests'

VideoClipsRequests.update({ data: video })
  .then(onVideoUpdate)
```

Have in mind that you can adjust the generated code by providing a **custom** template.

Benefits:

- Easily specify which routes should generate a helper.
- No need to manually specify the URL, preventing mistakes and saving development time.
- Plays nicely with tree-shaking, unused helpers are not included in the compiled bundle.